# Path with double backslash in VS-Code Task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to create a VS-Code task, that executs a R command to convert markdown into PDF. My current task looks like this:

```
{
    "label": "rmarkdown -> pdf",
    "type": "process",
    "command": "Rscript",
    "args": ["-e", "\"rmarkdown::render('${file}', 'pdf_document')\""],
    "windows": true,
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
    }
}
```

The problem ist, that `${file}` returns a path like this:

> d:\data\documents\myFile.md

but R needs a path with escaped backslashs like this:

> d:\\data\\documents\\myFile.md

how to get a escaped path from `${file}`?

Alternative a path with normal slashs will do the job as well, because R will automaticaly replace `/` to `\\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode is designed to return paths with platform-specific separators.

As a typical workaround, you can create an intermediate script that will condition arguments passed into it from a task and then call your tool.

Relevant discussion in vscode issue tracker: [#70050](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70050).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Killy.MXI. Ofcourse you are right, that is a workaround. But I don't want to create a script for that.

Comment: I think the best way to address this would be to file a proposal for a way to specify separators for path variables that VSCode dev team will be ready to accept. So far I've only seen mentions of a replace syntax, ugly enough to be turned down.

Comment: I think it is possible to write the intermediate script completely inside the task args, but escaping of two layers of scripting will be a pain. Separate script is much more maintainable.

Comment: Yes I think you are right with the possibility to write a script into the arguments. But I don't agree with you about the replacement. I don't know anything about the code of VS-Code. But I think that VS-Code only replaces ${file} during execution. So why should a further replace function, that enables custom replacement be ugly.